# Is there any way to add more spaces to Ubuntu Drive (where the home is)?

Tags: 14.04, android, android-studio

I've recently moved from windows to Ubuntu. I was learning Android App Developing with Android Studio.

I, stupidly enough, gave my Ubuntu partition only 20GiB. But Android Studio takes a huge amount of space, which clearly, this drive can't provide.

So,I must add more space to it. Question is, is there any way to do so? If yes, then how?

Comment: Could you add the output of this command: `df -h`? It will help us to know how your disk is formatted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you wanting to change your partition sizes (say shrinking your `/` partition then growing your `/home` partition)?

If so use gparted, which you can install by running:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted && gksudo gparted
```

If you are wanting to add another hard disk and move your data from `/home` to this drive, it's about the same.

In gparted highlight the partition you wish to move and select copy, then select the disk you wish to move the partition to and paste it.

Then grow the partition to fill the rest of the drive and execute (I think it's called run, looks like an enter symbol)